# How to publish WebApi and WebApp into two domains while resitricting access?

Tags: architecture, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I have a web project project with the following structure:

```
WebProject
- Controllers
    - API
        - SubscriptionController
        - UserController
    - SubscriptionController
- Views
    - Subscription
        - Confirmation.cshtml
        - ConfirmationSuccessfull.cshtml
```

Let's assume I'm dealing with subscriptions so my API exposes methods to create a new subscription or to cancel one. These methods are called from outside applications.

As part of the requirements the user needs to confirm his subscription. That is made by accessing a URL and upon the confirmation the user will get a success page.

Here comes the catch: I want the the API to be exposed in an address like (http://api.myapp.com/subscription -> for subscription api controller) and the confirmation part of the project in another address (http://myapp.com/subscription/confirm -> for subscription confirmation) but I **do not** want to be able to access the website part in the API url and vice versa.

I thought about restricting this in two different ways:

1. Keep the application in one IIS site answering to both domains and inspecting the host header that came with the request and look where to route. If a website call comes in from the api domain returns a 404. The problem here is having the domain restriction somewhat "hardcoded" in the code and also having to deal with this kind of infrastructure inside the code.
2. Separate the applicaiton in two different webprojects and deploy them in different websites in IIS. This is the cleanest way to handle the requirement, but it brings complexity I would rather not deal with. I would have to manage two different sites in two different folders with two different pieces of code and deployment process.

So, is there a third option, preferably with the best of both worlds?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried working with MVC Areas?

Comment: You can control that at the routing level or at the IIS level, I don't think there's a middle term. What's wrong with option 1 (dealing at the routing)? If you're worried about hard coding infrastructure configurations, just promote them to web.config

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I don't think MVC areas would fit his requirements. WebApi doesn't use the same routing that MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 would be very simple to implement and not require any real infrastructure as such. Just a simple custom route constraint. I attempted to show how the host header can be used to control routing in a previous question [How to configure Webapi Selfhosted for multiple HostHeaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882811/how-to-configure-webapi-selfhosted-for-multiple-hostheaders/13891801#13891801).